# Why ByteString is not Vector Word8?

Tags: performance, haskell, vector, bytestring

Seems like strict `ByteString` is structuraly same as `Vector Word8`. Why `ByteString` is not deprecated in favor of `Vector`?

Are there performance examples when `ByteString` is faster than `Vector Byte8`?

Comment: Are you aware of https://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-bytestring ?

Comment: Really, it's basically the same thing.  If you look at [the implementation](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/bytestring-0.9.2.1/docs/src/Data-ByteString-Internal.html#ByteString) on Hackage it's just a `ForeignPtr Word8` with offset and length metadata, which makes it nothing more than a C array of `Word8`s.  A `Vector` is a length annotated `Array`, which is a GHC primitive of a C-style array (IIRC).  The implementation details are different, but the underlying memory structure is pretty much the same.

Comment: However the garbage collector interaction is quite different, and many bytestring functions apparently use mutation in the implementation.

Comment: @GaneshSittampalam Good point, I hadn't considered that.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The [`vector-bytestring`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-bytestring-0.0.0.1/docs/Data-Vector-Storable-ByteString.html) package is an attempt at doing exactly this:

```
type ByteString = Vector Word8
```

[The goal of the author is to replace `bytestring`](http://www.haskell.org/pipermail/haskell/2011-October/023021.html), but for now there are some performance regressions and it doesn't seem very active.

According to the author, the main reason for the performance regressions are that `bytestring` often uses mutation internally. `vector-bytestring` might have an advantage in some cases where stream fusion kicks in, but otherwise it may need to fall back to mutation to get comparable performance and it doesn't do that yet.

Comment: Thanks! Though I'm more interested why folks don't invest into this library, seems like benchmarks may be outdated. I've submitted one of tests to `bytestring` guys, but noanswer =( https://github.com/haskell/bytestring/issues/23

Comment: Unfortunately the link with details of the ideas about how to fall back to mutation is dead (http://trac.haskell.org/vector/ticket/60). I guess in general it just needs people with the time to spare to work on it.

Comment: Note also that bytestring uses pinned ForeignPtrs, which has benefits and downsides. Benefits: zero-copy interaction with foreign libraries (i.e. network libraries). Downsides: fragmentation